# Relation: pairwise and mutually

Tags: probability-theory, elementary-set-theory, relations

1. Suppose we can define a relation $R$
   over the sets $X_1, …, X_k$  for any
   natural number $k$, note not
   specified for a particular $k$. I
   was wondering if there is some
   definition or conditions concerning
   the following situation:

   For any natural number $k$, and any 
   elements $\{ x_1 \in X_1, …, x_k \in
       X_k \}$,  existence of the relation
   for any two of the elements and
   existence of the relation for these
   $k$ elements imply each other? In
   other words, existence of pairwise
   relation and existence of mutual
   relation are equivalent?
2. For example,

   In probability theory, for a
   (finite, countably infinite,
   uncountably infinite) set of events,
   mutual independence implies pairwise
   independence, but pairwise
   independence does not imply mutual
   independence. I was wondering why?
   Specifically what kind of property does
   measure space lack to make the two
   equivalent?

Thanks and regards!

Comment: Here's a link to a relevant Wikipedia section:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mutual_independence#More_than_two_events

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that with a second part you provide a counterexample for a first part of your question. I will say, that the case with independence (when pairwise do not imply mutual) is a "usual" (general) case while implication is a special case. I think it's natural to find properties which leads to the implication $pairwise\to mutual$ than vice-versa like you are trying.

A nice example also is a relation of intersection. If any two sets in the class intersects it doesn't mean that there exists a common intersection.

On the other hand for the relations $=$ and $\neq$ admit this implication, so transitivity is not necessary.

Comment: Thanks! In the last sentence, how does transitivity not necessary come from = and ≠?

Comment: $\neq$ is not transitive. But for this relation an implication does hold.