# Example relations: pairwise versus mutual

Tags: big-list, relations, relation-algebra

There are by now several questions on math.se asking about pairwise versus mutual relations, eg:

• [When does “pairwise” strengthen and when does it weaken?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/132719/when-does-pairwise-strengthen-and-when-does-it-weaken)

• [Relation: pairwise and mutually](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/32798/relation-pairwise-and-mutually)

• [Categories of n-ary relations?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/279831/categories-of-n-ary-relations)

But confusion remains:

> I used to ponder this question some time ago but didn't come up with a
>   satisfactory answer. The problem seems to be that until someone gives
>   a formal treatment of the adjective "pairwise" in mathematics, it must
>   remain a linguistic problem. (user23211)

This phenomenon can be written for a [variadic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variadic_function), 2-valued relation $R$ as: $Rab∧Rbc∧Rac∧¬Rabc$.

4x examples:

• *Set intersection*: "If any two sets intersect it doesn't mean that there exists a common intersection." (Ilya)

• *Coprimality*: "We have "pairwise coprime" and "coprime". A non-empty set of natural numbers S is pairwise coprime iff $\forall s_1,s_2\in\mathcal S\;\gcd(s_1,s_2)=1$. $S$ is coprime iff $gcd(S)=1$. (user23211)

• *Statistical Independence*: Pairwise independence of 3 random variables $X, Y, Z$, $P(XY)=P(X)P(Y)$ and $P(XZ)=P(X)P(Z)$ and $P(YZ)=P(Y)P(Z)$ is independent of $P(XYZ)=P(X)P(Y)P(Z)$. The following figure displays this situation graphically with binomial r.v's.

[image]

• *Topological Linking*: The pairwise [Gauss linking number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linking_number) of any two links in the 3-component Borromean link is zero. Note, the linking number may be zero even for 2 linked rings, eg [Whitehead links](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whitehead_link). Further, the Gauss linking number is a pairwise relation, as far as I know, it cannot measure the linking of 3 or more components, in fact this motivated development of the [Massey product](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Massey_product). Nevertheless, topological linking itself is a variadic relation.

[image]

Are there other examples from combinatorial geometry and other branches of mathematics?

(Note the [Helly theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Helly%27s_theorem) in convex geometry states that a sufficient number of intersecting convex sets implies that they all intersect - so that would not be an example of the sought type of relation.)

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: @B.D, "big list", what other examples are there of this phenomenon?