# Proof that mutual statistical independence implies pairwise independence

Tags: probability, statistics, relations

This question about pairwise vs. mutual relations is related some extant questions: [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/283579/how-to-model-mutual-independence-in-bayesian-networks) and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/281800/example-relations-pairwise-versus-mutual).

Kobayashi, Mark & Turin's [*Probability, Random Processes and Statistical Analysis*](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0521895448), 2012, states without proof:

> three events, A, B, C are mutually independent when:
>
> P[A,B]=P[A]P[B], P[B,C]=P[B]P[C], P[A,C]=P[A]P[C],
>   P[A,B,C]=P[A]P[B]P[C]
>
> *No three of these relations necessarily imply the fourth*. [my italics]

However, [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pairwise_independence) and others generally agree that mutual independence implies pairwise independence, but also without a demonstration.

What is the simplest proof that mutual independence implies pairwise independence?

Note: GC Rota wrote that probability can be understood by focusing on random variables or focusing on distributions. However, the two views should be equivalent, correct?

Comment: The assertion is that no three of the relations imply the fourth. That is true. Of course the four relations imply the first three, but that is not what is being said.

Comment: Mutual independence is the fourth equality only, not all four.

Comment: @AndréNicolas, ok, I mistakenly assumed that mutual statistical independence behaved like "mutual relation".

Comment: The fourth relation does not imply the others. Let $A$ and $B$ be highly dependent events, and let $\Pr(C)=0$. (There are less trivial examples!)

Comment: Understood. I used the wrong definition of mutual statistical independence.

Comment: @AndréNicolas, what about in terms of factorization of the PDFs of 3 random variables, rather than in terms of events (since there are no zero PDFs)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mutual independence means the four identities you copied, pairwise independence means the first three of these identities. Ergo.

Comment: Mutual independence means the *last* of the identities, not all four. Please clarify?

Comment: Mutual independence means all four of the identities, not only the last one. Please grab **any** textbook.

Comment: I see, ok, +1. Then there is an ambiguity in mutual statistical dependence versus mutual relation as opposed to pairwise relation.

Comment: Ok, my mistake is definitional.

Comment: what I meant to ask - but did not phrase properly - is whether *properly* mutual independence (ie, the last equality as opposed to all four) implies pairwise independence.

Answer (score 2):

For an example where $P[A,B,C]=P[A]P[B]P[C]$ does not imply $P[A,B]=P[A]P[B], P[B,C]=P[B]P[C], P[A,C]=P[A]P[C]$ consider the distribution with indicators:

```
A  B  C  Prob
1  1  1   1/8
1  1  0   3/8
0  0  1   3/8
0  0  0   1/8
```

So $P[A]=P[B]=P[C]=\frac12$ and $P[A]P[B]P[C]=\frac18$ but $P[A,B]=\frac12, P[B,C]=\frac18, P[A,C]=\frac18$

In such as case, $A,B,C$ are not mutually independent