# mutual independence implies pairwise independence show that the converse is not true.

Tags: probability

We know:

**Mutual Independence** :

For $n‎\geq‎‎‎‎3$, random variables $X_1,X_2,...,X_n$ are mutually independent if $$ p(x_1,x_2,...,x_n)=p(x_1)p(x_2)...p(x_n)$$ for all $x_1,x_2,...,x_n$.

**Pairwise Independence** :

For $n‎\geq‎‎‎‎3$, random variables $X_1,X_2,...,X_n$ are pairwise independent if $ X_i,X_j$ are independent for all $1\leq i<j\leq n$.

Note that mutual independence implies pairwise independence.([Proof that mutual statistical independence implies pairwise independence](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/287116/370588))
show that the converse is not true.

Personally, I think the answer is cleared with the definition of 'Conditional Independence', but any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Easiest example:  Suppose three people are each tossing a fair coin.  Consider the three events $(A,B)$ match, $(B,C)$ match, and $(A,C)$ match.

Clearly these are pairwise independent.  But any two determine the third.

Comment: Sir shouldnt the mutual independence means that all terms should be pairwise indepedend and all simultaneously independent isnt ? If even one fails its not really necessary other three will be true right ? All four must be satified for mutual independence (for three events case )

Comment: @ProblemDestroyer  Yes.  But the problem here asked for an example in which pairwise independence held but mutual independence failed.